# Can't find my bones in vertex groups?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm trying to weight paint my armiture to my mesh. I put the armiture in pose mode, select the mesh, go to weight paint, but when there I am unable to select a bone. It allows me to paint the mesh, but doesn't weight it to any bones. There are no bones appearing in my vertex groups until I begin to paint, which suddenly produces an item called "Group". I don't know what I'm missing. The tutorials make it seem so simple.

Comment: Hello. First, you have to parent the mesh to the armature.

Comment: Select the mesh, shift select the armature and press Ctrl P, then choose "with empty groups" option if you want to hand paint them, or "automatic weight" if you want to have a base starting point.

Comment: Thanks so much you guys. That was exactly the problem. Doh.